# Fir kernel distribution to my data

Tags: python, kernel

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
from numpy import linspace,hstack


LINE_WIDTH = 3

filename=('')
data=[ map(float, line.split()) for line in open(filename,'r') if line.strip()]
dataM=np.array(data)
meandata=np.mean(dataM,axis=0)
SD = np.std(dataM,axis=0)

sns.set_palette("hls")
mpl.rc("figure", figsize=(8, 4))
xs = np.linspace(meandata[0]-(4 * SD[0]) ,meandata[0]+( 4 * SD[0]), dataM[:,0].size)
ys=dataM[:,0]
n,bins,patches=plt.hist(ys,15)
```

I get this plot.

[image]

and I want to get a kernel gaussian distribution plotted over my histogram but I  am getting an error TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

When I am trying to do this

```
my_pdf = gaussian_kde(ys)
x = linspace(30,100,1000)
plt(x,my_pdf(x),'r') # distribution function
plt.hist(ys,normed=1,alpha=.3) # histogram
plt.show()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://s17.postimg.org/jut9xqwcf/ssa.png

Comment: Place that link inside you question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly using [seaborn](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/plotting_distributions.html). It would be something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('input.txt')
sns.distplot(data, kde=False, fit=scipy.stats.norm)
plt.show()
```

For a kde plot just do:

```
sns.distplot(data);
```

[image]

Comment: Yes i have used sns.distplt, but then i want to fill the area with 3sigma rule but fill_between does not work with distplot, or at least i do not know how. Could you help? I mean i want different shape at values μ-2σ<data<m+2σ, μ-2σ<data<m+2σ etc